# Oneliner to get a string representation of Day of week, day of month and time according to default locale

Tags: java, date, date-format, simpledateformat, date-formatting

I'm using a combination of `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat` to achive following string from a `Date` object:

```
fre 20 22:48
```

This snippet produces the outcome above:

```
DateFormat localizedTimeFormatter = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
String str = new SimpleDateFormat("EE d", Locale.getDefault()).format(date) + " " + localizedTimeFormatter.format(date);
```

The outcome is exactly as I want, but I think there are improvements that could be done. I would like to use only the `SimpleDateFormat` to achieve this and getting shortname for day in week and day of month are not the problem. The problem is getting time in only hours and minutes according to locale, or more correctly, 12 or 24 hour format. I've checked out the documentation on the `SimpleDateFormat` [Javadoc SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
but as I can see there are no way of getting a time(hhmm) in 12 or 24hour format just by setting a format string to the `SimpleDateFormat`? Are there any way to achieve this by only using `SimpleDateFormat` as a oneliner, or do I have to do it the way I have done already, or are there a completely different way of solving this little issue?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EE d HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
```

or

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EE d hh:mm", Locale.getDefault());
```

Comment: I've tried this solution before and this still needs me to write logic for figuring out if 12 or 24hour clock is being used in order to locale.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is on the right track. 
However, I didn't need to use the DateFormatter.

I got your expected result in this line itself.

```
      String str = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d, k:m", Locale.getDefault()).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Output is:

```
      Mon, 30, 19:5
```

The pattern you use in the first argument to SimpleDateFormat is the key here I think. 
The meaning of the individual alphabets and their combination is already mentioned in the link you gave.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solution doesn't automatically add AM/PM to the time and neither uses 12 or 24 hour according to locale.
The solution I want is if for example en_US is the default locale then the time would be displayed lika 5:24PM and if for example the locale sv_FI is used then 17:24 would be displayed. But maybe it's not possible to set up a formatter like this